# Unable to connect to LXD API

Tags: lxd

I have successfully installed the LXD 3.13 snap package. I have run `lxd init` and added myself to the lxd group, and am able to create containers:

```
$ lxc launch ubuntu: example
Creating example
Starting example
```

However, I am unable to connect to the REST API. I tried running `curl --unix-socket /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket s/` as per [here](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2016/04/19/directly-interacting-with-the-lxd-api), a response of `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server` is given.

Using [node-lxd](https://github.com/alandoherty/node-lxd), I also receive an error saying:

```
constructor {
  _message: 'HTTP Error',
  _status: 'Failed',
  _statusCode: 400,
  _innerError:
   { Error: connect ENOENT /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
       at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)
     errno: 'ENOENT',
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'connect' } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unix socket for the **snap** package of LXD is at

```
/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket
```

You have been using the path for the Unix socket of the `apt` package of LXD.